# Python minecraft pyglet glClear() skipping frames

Tags: python, opengl, frame, minecraft, pyglet

I recently downloaded fogleman's excellent "Minecraft in 500 lines" demo from https://github.com/fogleman/Craft. I used the 2to3 tool and corrected some details by hand to make it runnable under python3. I am now wondering about a thing with the call of `self.clear()` in the render method. This is my modified rendering method that is called every frame by pyglet:

```
def on_draw(self):
    """ Called by pyglet to draw the canvas.

    """
    frameStart = time.time()
    self.clear()
    clearTime = time.time()
    self.set_3d()
    glColor3d(1, 1, 1)
    self.model.batch.draw()
    self.draw_focused_block()
    self.set_2d()
    self.draw_label()
    self.draw_reticle()
    renderTime = time.time()

    self.clearBuffer.append(str(clearTime - frameStart))
    self.renderBuffer.append(str(renderTime - clearTime))
```

As you can see, I took the execution times of `self.clear()` and the rest of the rendering method. The call of `self.clear()` calls this method of pyglet, that can be found at *.../pyglet/window/__init__.py*:

```
def clear(self):
    '''Clear the window.

    This is a convenience method for clearing the color and depth
    buffer.  The window must be the active context (see `switch_to`).
    '''
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

So I basically do make a call to `glClear()`.
I noticed some frame drops while testing the game (at 60 FPS), so I added the above code to measure the execution time of the commands, and especially that one of `glClear()`. I found out that the rendering itself never takes longer than 10 ms. But the duration of `glClear()` is a bit of a different story, here is the distribution for 3 measurements under different conditions:
[Duration of glClear() under different conditions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA2z7.png)

The magenta lines show the time limit of a frame. So everything behind the first line means there was a frame drop.
The execution time of glClear() seems to have some kind of "echo" after the first frame expires. Can you explain me why? And how can I make the call faster?
Unfortunately I am not an OpenGL expert, so I am thankful for every advice guys. ;)

Comment: It could be that your timers resolution is simply 16 ms, which would explain the "echo". See https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time which says "not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.". Try a different timer, and see if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph is wrong. Well, at least it's not a suitable graph for the purpose of measuring performance. Don't ever trust a `gl*` function to execute when you tell it to, and don't ever trust it to execute as fast as you'd expect it to.

Most `gl*` functions aren't executed right away, they couldn't be. Remember, we're dealing with the GPU, telling it to do stuff directly is slow. So, instead, we write a to-do list (a command queue) for the GPU, and dump it into VRAM when we *really* need the GPU to output something. This "dump" is part of a process called synchronisation, and we can trigger one with `glFlush`. Though, OpenGL is user friendly (compared to, say, Vulkan, at least), and as such it doesn't rely on us to explicitly flush the command queue. Many `gl*` functions, which exactly depending on your graphics driver, will implicitly synchronise the CPU and GPU state, which includes a flush.

Since `glClear` usually initiates a frame, it is possible that your driver thinks it'd be good to perform such an implicit synchronisation. As you might imagine, synchronisation is a very slow process and blocks CPU execution until it's finished.

And this is probably what's going on here. Part of the synchronisation process is to perform memory transactions (like `glBufferData`, `glTexImage*`), which are probably queued up until they're flushed with your `glClear` call. Which makes sense in your example; the spikes that we can observe are probably the frames after you've uploaded a lot of block data.

But bear in mind, this is just pure speculation, and I'm not a total expert on this sort of stuff either, so don't trust me on the exact details. [This page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization) on the OpenGL wiki is a good resource on this sort of thing.

Though one thing is certain, your `glClear` call does not take as long as your profiler says it does. You should be using a profiler dedicated to profiling graphics.